# Rasterizing 3d plot adds a weird frame

Tags: plotting, rasterize

I am trying to export a 3d plot of good quality.
Here is a MWE:

```
ptest = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
Export["test.pdf", 
 Rasterize[ptest, ImageResolution -> 100, Background -> White], 
 Frame -> False, FrameStyle -> White]
```

The problem is that after exporting there is a weird frame in the pdf file. It seems like there is some shade apparent in the bottom and right edge of the file. See the red arrow in the attached picture.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

My Mathematica version is

```
"12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"
```

My Mac OS version is:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.5.2
BuildVersion:   20G95
```

To see this issue better, here is a screenshot from a tex document:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please run $Version and include version info along with your OS details.

Comment: I don't see the frame on MMA 12.0, macOS 10.14.

Comment: @N.J.Evans I am running macOS 11.5. Are you sure you don't see it? In my case I didn't see it straight away, but when I included the figure in a tex document it was very visible.

Comment: I don't see it on MMA 13.0

Comment: @bobsacameno I tried including it in a TeX document and it still looks fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce, but would `ImagePad` help here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappears when I changed the file suffix from `pdf` to `png`.

Namely using

```
ptest = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
Export["test.png", 
 Rasterize[ptest, ImageResolution -> 100, Background -> White], 
 Frame -> False, FrameStyle -> White]
```